# The control type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' is not allowed on this page. The type is not registered as safe

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, reportviewer, reportviewer2008

I am trying to register the   'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' assembly in my web.config file. I tried everyting could not make this thing work.

```
<SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Check whether the dll version matches with the version in the safe control entry.

Answer (score 0):

You could need a binding redirect from version 8 to 9. You might need another binding redirect to handle some things that were used in 8 but aren't present in 9. I [found this](http://collab.rdacorp.com/2009/06/coexistence-of-report-viewer-versions.html) while searching for an answer to my version 8 -> version 10 problem. I describes side-by-side configuration of 8 and 9 in MOSS.